# Text disappears when using SVG

Tags: css

I'm trying to create some text that scales to fit 100% of the container's width. When I use div instead of svg, the text is visible but doesn't scale. When I switch to svg, the text disappears entirely. Am I not using the correct syntax? In researching I've seen several people talk about using svg to get text to scale responsively, but all of the examples are so complex I can't figure out how to apply it to my project. This is what I'm trying to do

```
<svg id="title", class="title">Test</svg>
```

```
.title {
    position: absolute;
    background: grey;
    height: 100%;
    width: 33.33vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    left: 0%;
}
```

Here's my code pen with the full code:
https://codepen.io/TheNomadicAspie/pen/NWjKwxE

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:
Refer this article to know more about SVG element **<**text**>** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text

```css
.txtSize { font: italic 10rem serif; fill: red; }
```

```html
<svg id="title" class="title">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="grey" />
  <text  x="20" y="90%" class="txtSize">Test</text>
</svg>
```